# Warp effect for SKSpriteNodes passing through it?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skeffectnode

I'm trying to apply a warp/distortion effect to all SKSpriteNodes that pass through a fixed rectangle sized area on the screen. Shown in the image below, the same SKSpriteNode will start at the top of the screen and work its way down allowing the rectangle distortion filter to warp the node as it passes through.

I've tried using a SKEffectNode shown in the code below. However, I couldn't set a fixed height and width value to the SKEffectNode which later gave me inconsistent warp effects due the SKEffectNode constantly changing its height to accommodate all the SKSpritNode children.

I'm wondering if there is another way to achieve this effect or if I'm missing something with the SKEffectNode. Ideally I'd like the the warp to effect any SKNode that passes under it without the need to add and remove children.

Any information would be much appreciated.

[image]

Warp effect I'm trying to achieve above and current SKEffectNode code below.

```
 func warpToUpEffectNode(effectNode:SKEffectNode, view:SKView){
    effectNode.zPosition = priorityPos.upEffectNodeZ
    let destinationPositions: [vector_float2] = [
        vector_float2(-0.1, 1), vector_float2(0.5, 1.3), vector_float2(1.1, 1),
        vector_float2(0.1, 0.5), vector_float2(0.5, 0.5), vector_float2(0.9, 0.5),
        vector_float2(-0.1, 0), vector_float2(0.5, -0.3), vector_float2(1.1, 0)
    ]
    let warpGeometryGrid = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 10,rows: 1)
    effectNode.warpGeometry = warpGeometryGrid.replacingByDestinationPositions(positions: destinationPositions)
}
```

Comment: Since `SKScene` is an `SKEffectNode`, perhaps you can set `warpGeometry` appropriately on the whole scene?  Alternatively maybe use a custom shader for the scene that computes the relevant distortion in a certain region.  I've used the latter approach for special effects that change the whole game's graphics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, what would you recommend to build a custom shader? So far I've found Metal and OpenGL ES

Comment: As far as I know, only OpenGL style is allowed with SpriteKit.  Or sort of at least.  It's translated to Metal under the hood, and some more advanced stuff doesn't get translated but works if you use Metal syntax.  There's an example with mixed OpenGL + Metal at https://github.com/bg2b/RockRats/blob/master/Asteroids/scenes/GameScene.swift if you search for `RetroShader`.  That's one of the special effects scene shaders that I mentioned earlier.  The game's graphics are normally full color, but that turns the whole scene to a black-and-white outline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can accomplish this using render-to-texture.

[image]

first, put all of your scene elements into a single large node, i'm calling it `container`

then set up your viewport area, the part you want to warp. it's a bit tricky because you also have to crop it (otherwise you'll see the fringe of the warped shape)

```
/*
 create a crop node with
 - mask
 - a visible frame
 - a warpable spritenode
 */
viewport_warp = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))
let viewport_frame = SKShapeNode(rectOf: viewport_warp.size, cornerRadius: 15)
viewport_frame.strokeColor = .black
viewport_frame.zPosition = 3
viewport_warp.addChild(viewport_frame)

let viewport_mask = SKShapeNode(rectOf: viewport_warp.size, cornerRadius: 15)
viewport_mask.fillColor = .black

let cropNode = SKCropNode()
cropNode.zPosition = 2
cropNode.maskNode = viewport_mask
cropNode.addChild(viewport_warp)
addChild(cropNode)
```

then set up your warp geometry

```
//warp the geometry of the spritenode
let PINCH_OFFSET:Float = 0.1
let dst = [
    // bottom row: left, center, right
    vector_float2(0.0, 0.0),
    vector_float2(0.5, 0.0 - PINCH_OFFSET),
    vector_float2(1.0, 0.0),

    // middle row: left, center, right
    vector_float2(0.0 - PINCH_OFFSET, 0.5),
    vector_float2(0.5, 0.5),
    vector_float2(1.0 + PINCH_OFFSET, 0.5),

    // top row: left, center, right
    vector_float2(0.0, 1.0),
    vector_float2(0.5, 1.0 + PINCH_OFFSET),
    vector_float2(1.0, 1.0)
]
let warpGeometryGrid = SKWarpGeometryGrid(columns: 2,rows: 2)
viewport_warp.warpGeometry = warpGeometryGrid.replacingByDestinationPositions(positions: dst)
```

and finally, do render-to-texture on the `container` and update the texture of your spritenode

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let cropped_viewport = viewport_warp.frame.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10) //optional: adds magnification effect
    let texture:SKTexture? = self.view?.texture(from:container, crop:cropped_viewport)
    viewport_warp.texture = texture
}
```